# How can I merge the dates on this ledger?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tow tables for reciepts and expenture, am using union to merge them AND generate reports

```
SELECT  MIN(date) AS trx, MAX(date), COUNT(*), SUM(amount), CONCAT(' - ','-'),
    $f as _ 
FROM expenditure WHERE date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date'
    AND client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}'
GROUP BY _

UNION

SELECT  MIN(date) AS trx, MAX(date), COUNT(*),CONCAT(' - ','-'), SUM(amount),
    $f as _ 
FROM receipts
WHERE  date >= '$start_date'  AND date <= '$end_date'
   AND client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}'
GROUP BY _
ORDER BY trx
```

I get the following results

```
  Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-03-06 [MAX(date)] => 2012-03-06 [COUNT(*)] => 1 [SUM(amount)] => 120000 [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => - - [_] => 2012-03-06 )
          [1] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-03-08 [MAX(date)] => 2012-03-08 [COUNT(*)] => 1 [SUM(amount)] => 120000 [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => - - [_] => 2012-03-08 )
          [2] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-06-06 [MAX(date)] => 2012-06-06 [COUNT(*)] => 2 [SUM(amount)] => 60000 [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => - - [_] => 2012-06-06 ) 
          [3] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-06-06 [MAX(date)] => 2012-06-06 [COUNT(*)] => 1 [SUM(amount)] => - - [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => 487200 [_] => 2012-06-06 )
          [4] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-06-08 [MAX(date)] => 2012-06-08 [COUNT(*)] => 1 [SUM(amount)] => 120000 [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => - - [_] => 2012-06-08 )
          [5] => Array ( [trx] => 2012-06-29 [MAX(date)] => 2012-06-29 [COUNT(*)] => 2 [SUM(amount)] => 320000 [CONCAT(' - ','-')] => - - [_] => 2012-06-29 )  )
```

**problem**
If you notice on 3 and four there are two records for one day.

```
[trx] => 2012-06-06
```

Because on that day the client carried out both a credit and debit. is there  way to just only combine rows like 3 and 4 into one row. SELECT DISTINCT dindnt work either or is it posible for mysql to sum records from both tables that occur on the same date.

Comment: You've swapped the order of the fields CONCAT(' - ','-'), SUM(amount) in the 2 sub-queries here - if this isn't a cut and paste error you might want to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use the subselect for your custom aliases to group

```
$query = "
    SELECT q.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            MIN(date) AS trx, 
            MAX(date) as max_date, 
            COUNT(*), 
            SUM(amount), 
            CONCAT(' - ','-'),
            $f as _ 
        FROM 
            expenditure 
        WHERE 
            date >= '$start_date'  
            AND date <= '$end_date'  
            AND client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}' 
        GROUP BY _ 
    UNION
        SELECT  
            MIN(date) AS trx, 
            MAX(date), 
            COUNT(*),
            CONCAT(' - ','-'),
            SUM(amount), 
            $f as _ 
        FROM 
            receipts 
        WHERE  
            date >= '$start_date'  
            AND  date <= '$end_date'  
            AND  client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}' 
        GROUP BY _ ORDER BY trx 
    ) q GROUP BY q.max_date
";
```

Above query will group the results by  `MAX(date) as max_date`

And for the sum of amount on same date you can modify as

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        q.*, 
        SUM(q.amount) AS grand_sum 
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            MIN(date) AS trx, 
            MAX(date) as max_date, 
            COUNT(*), 
            SUM(amount) AS amount, 
            CONCAT(' - ','-'),
            $f as _ 
        FROM 
            expenditure 
        WHERE 
            date >= '$start_date'  
            AND date <= '$end_date'  
            AND client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}' 
        GROUP BY _ 
    UNION
        SELECT  
            MIN(date) AS trx, 
            MAX(date), 
            COUNT(*),
            CONCAT(' - ','-'),
            SUM(amount), 
            $f as _ 
        FROM 
            receipts 
        WHERE  
            date >= '$start_date'  
            AND  date <= '$end_date'  
            AND  client_id like '{$_SESSION['client']['id']}' 
        GROUP BY _ ORDER BY trx 
) q GROUP BY q.max_date
";
```

This `grand_sum` column has the sum of amount on the same date

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` the `expenditures` and `receipts` tables *first*, then select from the unioned result. Note that the unioned result has separate columns for `receipt.value` and `expenditure.value`.

```
SELECT
  MIN(date) as trx,
  MAX(date),
  COUNT(exp_amount) + COUNT(rct_amount) AS Tran_Count,
  COALESCE(SUM(exp_amount), ' - -') AS Exp_Total,
  COALESCE(SUM(rct_amount), ' - -') AS Rct_Total,
  _
FROM (
  SELECT whatever AS _, date, amount AS exp_amount, NULL AS rct_amount
    FROM expenditure
    WHERE date >= start AND date <= end AND client_id LIKE 'whatever'
  UNION SELECT whatever, date, NULL, amount
    FROM receipts
    WHERE date >= start AND date <= end AND client_id LIKE 'whatever'
) exp_rct
GROUP BY _
ORDER BY trx
```